# In Python, how can I read a text document line-by-line and print the number of same characters in a row at the end of each line?

Tags: python, text

I have a program which converts a simple image (black lines on white background) into 2 character ASCII art ("x" is black and "-" is white).

I want to read each line and print the number or same character in a row at the end of each line. Do you know how I can do this?

for example:

```
---x---  3 1 3
--xxx--  2 3 2
-xxxxx-  1 5 1
```

in the top row there are 3 dashes 1 'x' and 3 dashes, and so on.
I would like these numbers to be saved to the ASCII text document.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "Do you know how I can do this?" Well, what do you imagine are the logical steps to solving the problem? Where do you get stuck, when you attempt to write code to solve it? Can you do the "read each line" part, in the first place? Okay, then what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```py
from itertools import groupby

with open("art.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in map(lambda l: l.strip(), f):
        runs = [sum(1 for _ in g) for _, g in groupby(line)]
        print(f"{line} {' '.join(map(str, runs))}")

# ---x--- 3 1 3
# --xxx-- 2 3 2
# -xxxxx- 1 5 1
```